# POV-Ray 2D gradient (polygon)

Tags: colors, 2d, gradient, povray

So, what I want to do is apply a color gradient on a custom 2D polygon and I can't find anywhere instructions/examples on how to do it (all I can find are 3D ones). Specifically, I want to do this:

[image]

Also in general, I would like to know how to apply a simple radial gradient say from the center (of the polygon) out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out and since I can't seem to find a straight-forward answer anywhere I might as well answer my own question:

1) To do one gradient on your polygon you just need the spherical pigment with a color_map. I give an example with a triangle:

```
#declare pol1=polygon{3,<-1,0> <1,0> <0,1>} //Declare a triangle
polygon{pol1 pigment{spherical color_map{[0.0 rgb <1,0,0>] [1.0 rgb <0,0,1>] } translate<0,0,0>} }
```

So what this does is it creates a radial gradient with its center at the absolute (0,0,0) and you can translate it depending where you want it. The **color map** defines two colors (rgb <1,0,0> and rgb <0,0,1>) and the number in front of them basically controls the gradient (where the colors start/end relative to the grid system). Won't explain it in detail so you can read more [here](https://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/335/).

2) To do more gradients, say one for each corner I couldn't find a way to apply 3 different gradients on a single shape. Like **color_map** there is also a **gradient_map** but it's of no help because of the way you have to define where one pigment ends and where the next one starts. So the only way I found around this is by removing the polygon's corners with cylinders (with the [difference](https://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/306/) command) and then replace them with cylinders (with the [intersection](https://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.1/305/) command) whose phase is the desired gradient. And even though it's a messy way it doesn't actually impacts performance which is my main concern so I'm going with it until I find something better. So here is an example (I am not going to explain it any further, this answer is getting big as it is):

```
#declare pos1=array[2]{-1,0}; //the corners' coordinates
#declare pos2=array[2]{1,0};   
#declare pos3=array[2]{0,1};
#declare cyl_rad=0.5;     

#declare pol1=polygon{3,<pos1[0],pos1[1],0> <pos2[0],pos2[1],0> <pos3[0],pos3[1],0>} //Declare the polygon
#declare cyl1=cylinder{<pos1[0],pos1[1],-0.01> <pos1[0],pos1[1],0.01>,cyl_rad} //Declare the cylinder that will "replace" the first corner
#declare cyl2=cylinder{<pos2[0],pos2[1],-0.01> <pos2[0],pos2[1],0.01>,cyl_rad} //Declare the cylinder that will "replace" the second corner
#declare cyl3=cylinder{<pos3[0],pos3[1],-0.01> <pos3[0],pos3[1],0.01>,cyl_rad} //Declare the cylinder that will "replace" the third corner
difference{polygon{pol1} cyl1 cyl2 cyl3 pigment {color_part}} //The polygon with its corners "cut"
intersection{polygon{pol1} cyl3 pigment{spherical color_map{[0.0 rgb <1,0,0>] [0.95 rgb <0,0,1>]} scale<cyl_rad,cyl_rad,cyl_rad> translate <pos3[0],pos3[1],0>} } //Replacing the corners with the coloured cylinders
intersection{polygon{pol1} cyl2 pigment{spherical color_map{[0.0 rgb <1,0,0>] [0.95 rgb <0,1,1>]} scale<cyl_rad,cyl_rad,cyl_rad> translate <pos2[0],pos2[1],0>} }
intersection{polygon{pol1} cyl1 pigment{spherical color_map{[0.0 rgb <1,0,0>] [0.95 rgb <0,1,0>]} scale<cyl_rad,cyl_rad,cyl_rad> translate <pos1[0],pos1[1],0>} }
```